# recognize text and numbers with a dark background

Tags: python, python-tesseract

Base image
[image: base image]

My source code in Python 3:

```
from wand.image import Image
from wand.display import display

with Image(filename='edited.png') as img:
    with Image(img) as negate:
        negate.alpha_channel = False           
        negate.transform_colorspace('gray')
        negate.resize(width=negate.width*2, height=negate.height*2, filter='lanczos', blur=0.5)
        negate.negate()
        negate.contrast_stretch(black_point=0.00, white_point=0.8, channel=None)        
        negate.sharpen(radius=0, sigma=1)
        display(negate)
```

Prepared image to tesseract
[image: prepared image to tesseract]

We need to recognize numbers and some text. My solution is good, but it works 80%. Are there any options for how to do it better?

Comment: Since this is a design question rather than a code implementation question, maybe https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your solution works 80%, but if you use pytesseract version 4.1.1 the result will be below:

```
Horsepower 1,675 HPA Pen Value at 100m §92/654/600 Nm Soft Terrain Resistance 2.20

Top Forward Speed 67 KM/H Pen Value at 500m 584/645/600 wm Medium Terrain Resista 130

Top Reverse Speed 20 KM/H Pen Value at 1000m 575/635/600 Nw Firm Terrain Resistance 1.10

Hull Rotation Speed 26 DEG/S Pen Value at 2000m 552/610/600 Nw

Weight to Horsepower F 26.56 Detectability Range: Sti 407.08 a

Fire Chance 10.00% Armor Damage 5§35/535/535 He Detectability Range: Mo 426.04 _
Module Damage 190/190/190 He

Accuracy at 100m 0.26" Blast Radius 0/0/0m View Range 515 M

Aiming Time 2.10 sec Turret Rotation Speed a0 oes =f

Max Elevation 20 0&6 = Ammo Max Speed 1,700/1,575/1,140 mys Accuracy During Rotatic 0.83 :

Max Depression 9 DEG AmmoMax Range  3,500/3,500/2,800 Signal Range 690

Ammo Capacity 50 Hit Points 4,000 He

Reload Time 7.90 sec Yaw Limit -180 180 oes

Rate of Fire 7.59 RPM Shell Type 1 APFSDS

Shots Per Clip 1 Shell Type 2 APFSDS

Intra-clip reload N/A Shell Type 3 HEAT
```

I checked a few words and it matched with the original input image.

I used `opencv` instead of `wand`

Code:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

# Load the img
img = cv2.imread("XX2ry.png")

# Cvt to gry
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# OCR detection
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(gry, config="--psm 6")
print(txt)
```

Maybe you should check the [page segmentation methods](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#page-segmentation-method)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. I used the following pytessreact settings: custom_oem_psm_config = r '-- oem 1 --psm 11 -c tessedit_char_whitelist= ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYZabcdefjhijklmnopqrstuvwyz0123456789/.,-%' Results = pytesseract.image_to_string (img, lang = 'eng', config = custom_oem_psm_config)

Comment: Glad if I could help.